# Scheduled reminders for rolling renewals not sending after first renewal

Tags: scheduled-reminders

One set of our memberships is a 1-year, rolling product that can be purchased at any time.

We've set up tests for scheduled renewal reminders but it seems to have stopped working:

1. Entity: membership > individual membership
2. When: [1] [week] [before] [membership end date]
3. Enable repetition: yes
4. Repetition: every [1] [day] until [1] [day] [after] [membership end date]
5. 'From name/email' etc. added
6. Limited to Smart Group made up of test contacts

We initially set one of the test contacts up with a membership set to expire in 8 days. At 7 days before we got the first email, and each day after that until we changed the renewal end date to be a further 8 days in the future from that point (to test what would happen for the 2nd year renewal period).

After that, we no longer received any emails. Checked cron jobs etc. and send scheduled reminders is set to run daily.

Is there a problem with 'clearing out' contacts tat have been triggered to (e.g. once they have renewed once they'll never get sent the scheduled reminder again, even once they get to 1 week before membership end date once again)?

(we're using v4.6.9 in case that is relevant.)

Comment: There have been other issues with Scheduled Reminders not working if the End Date gets manually altered - searching might provide an answer, otherwise you could set up a membership type that is only on a 7 day cycle so you can test it without needing to alter the end date. if that is helpful i can convert to an answer (may do anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to further test whether this is just an issue resulting from manually changing the End Date would be to set up a membership type that is only on a 10 day cycle (or less if urgent) so you can test it without needing to alter the end date. if that is helpful i can convert to an answer (may do anyway)

Comment: That might be the root of the problem - do you know if the same issue would apply when the user renews through a renewal form (i.e. the membership end date is extended by a renewal _process_ rather than directly through manual changes in the Civi membership record?)

Comment: as i understand things the problem is only triggered by manual changes.

Comment: Hmm - this seems to have done the trick! Now I just need to work out why 1 of the four test users has got the reminders but 3 others have recieved nothing (nothing in the logs/contact records)...